# Prevent pauses between music tracks on YouTube Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I like to listen to an entire album at a time on YouTube. Many of the actual albums have songs that drift off into each other and all blend together. On YouTube, however, there is a pause in between each video ruining the effect.

Is there a way to prevent this pause between tracks?

Answer (score 1):

Since each video has to load individually, no, there's no way to prevent this. There are channels uploading full albums as one video however, you may want to use those instead of playlists. Or, well, use a "real" music service (spotify, google play music, CDs, etc.).